# Different internet conections to my virtual machines

Tags: windows-7, internet, virtual-machine

I want to install 8 virtual machines/virtual desktops on my home desktop PC (and only for my own personal use and all the 8 machines will run at the same time) and I want to be able to choose what internet connection I want for every of the 8 virtual machines/desktops (curently I have 1 ISP1 cable conection and 1 ISP2 HSPDA USB modem = 2 Internet connections but I intend to buy several subscriptions to other ISPs so that I'll have completely different IP addresses). My OS is Windows 7 Professional 64-bit and I intend on each of the 8 machines to install Windows XP. Do you think I need a Type 1 hypervisor for this or what do you think is the best software that I should use? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox can do this using bridged networking. See [Chapter 6 in the VirtualBox documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#id403166) for details.

Comment: I can also use VMware ESXi ? I understand that it's Type 1 hypervisor so this should bring a big improvement in performance to my 8 virtual machines ?

Comment: I am not familiar with bare-metal Type 1 hypervisors, so I can't say whether it can link each network interface directly to each virtual machine.  However, I am aware that VirtualBox is capable of doing so by means of bridged networking.  In addition, I do not believe that a Type 1 hypervisor will lead to a very large increase in performance compared to a Type 2 hypervisor given hardware-assisted virtualization, but it may be somewhat faster overall.

Comment: I installed VirtualBox and i have 1 virtual machine. When i go to Settings-Network-Adapter 1 and choose Attached to : Bridged adapter the only option in the list is my Asus Nx1101 Gigabit Internet Adapter. If i want this machine to be conected to internet using my Huawei3G Mobile internet (conected by Usb) what should i do ? Thank's

Comment: I'm not sure if VirtualBox sees the mobile broadband modem.  Is the modem correctly connected to the computer and can the host operating system use it?

Comment: @Ilario, you may need to install the [VirtualBox Extension Pack](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#intro-installing), which includes USB capability for virtual machines, in order to use the modem.  Unfortunately, as I am not familiar with bridged networking (I have only briefly read about it) or configuring USB in VirtualBox, you will need to consult with the [user manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html).

Comment: Ok..thank's for the info. I think i will just use the Nat option (using the host internet conection) for 4 of the virtual machines and then each new machine should have its own different ip conection from different Isp-s